# Semiconductor mass action law question

Tags: semiconductors, solid-state-devices

I was told that the mass action law $$np = n_i^2$$ 
only applies to compensated semiconductors and intrinsic semiconductors, and it does not apply to n-type or p-type semiconductors. Is this true? I also heard the argument that the hole concentration decreases as the electron concentration increases in case of a n-type doping, therefore the mass action law is still applicable. I am not sure which is right, but I am sure I am missing something here.

When solving problems such as the one below

[image]

*Source: Semiconductor physics and devices, Donald A. Neamen*

I am not sure whether I can apply the mass action law or not. For example, could part (b) solved using the mass action law since the electron concentration is given?
$$p_o = n_i^2/n_o$$

Please help me understand when I can or cannot apply the mass action law.

Comment: The mass action law is applicable to n-type and p-type semiconductors. I could derive this for you, even in the case of graded materials, by developing the Boltzman equations for both n and p and then multiplying them together to get the relationship, which essentially states that the product, \$n\cdot p\$, is a constant that is independent of the position \$x\$ in the material and therefore, under thermal equilibrium at least, independent of the amount of doping. Since an intrinsic semiconductor's \$n=p=n_i\$, it directly follows that \$n\:p=n_i^2\$. Where exactly did you read/hear otherwise?